# Is there a way to make an extension for a generic type object?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, class-extensions

so I'm trying to make an exception to map my C# class to an proto object via extension methods it doesn't seem to accept a generic type for "this"?

```
 public static ResponseReply ToProtoObject(this Response<T> reply) {
        ResponseReply answer = new() { 
            Succes = reply.Success
        };
        if (reply.Object != null)
        {
            answer.ObjectId = reply.Object.Id.ToString();
        }

        if (reply.Messages != null)
        {
            answer.Messages.AddRange(reply.Messages.Select(x => x.ToProtoObject()));
        }


        return answer;
    }
```

these are the base classes from the Response

```
    public class Response<T> where T : BaseObjectBo
{
    public T Object { get; set; }
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    public List<Message> Messages { get; set; }
}
public class BaseObjectBo
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You seem to be missing a `<T>` between `ToProtoObject` and the opening parens.

Comment: You appear to be missing a type parameter declaration on your method

Comment: (Also, all of LINQ is based on extension methods on generic types...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note, you just need to add `<T>` to your method signature.

```
public static ResponseReply ToProtoObject<T>(this Response<T> reply) 
    where T : BaseObjectBo
```

Comment: I changed it but now I get another error about
"The type 'T' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Response<T>'. There is no boxing conversion or type parameter conversion from 'T' to 'BaseObjectBo'."

Comment: @Jonasgo You probably need to restrict `T` to `BaseObjectBo` too: `public static ResponseReply ToProtoObject(this Response<T> reply) where T: BaseObjectBo`

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto that did it thank you so much ^_^